# Inequalities for $\sin$ and $\cos$

Tags: trigonometry

I was working on a problem for math, and in the back of the book, we are given that $|\sin\theta|$ $\leq$ $|\theta|$. It got me thinking, are there any other properties similar to this one that applies to $\cos$ or any of the other trigonometric inequalities?

Comment: There are plenty, but you need to be specific. Too broad questions aren't very popular.

Comment: For example you will find some [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240437/proof-that-frac3-pi8-int-0-pi-2-cos-sinx-dx-frac49-pi12/3240477#3240477), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795803/how-to-see-cos-x-leq-exp-x2-2-on-x-in-0-pi-2/1795885#1795885)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that

$$\cos\theta\le 1.$$

Then integrating from $0$ to $\theta$,

$$\sin\theta\le\theta.$$

Then integrating from $0$ to $\theta$,

$$1-\cos\theta\le\frac{\theta^2}2.$$

Then integrating from $0$ to $\theta$,

$$\theta-\sin\theta\le\frac{\theta^3}6.$$

Then integrating from $0$ to $\theta$,

$$\frac{\theta^2}2+\cos\theta-1\le\frac{\theta^4}{24}.$$

And so on. This re-establishes the Taylor expansion, with a guaranteed bound. (You can symmetrize using parity arguments.)

Answer (score 1):

Among the well known inequality we can also show that

$$\cos \theta  \ge 1-\frac12 \theta^2$$

indeed by trigonometric identities we have that

$$\cos(\theta)=1-2\sin^2 \left(\frac \theta 2\right) \ge 1-2\left(\frac \theta 2\right)^2=1-\frac12 \theta^2$$

and many other similar inequality can be obtained by geometrical consideration or mainly by Taylor's series.

Refer to the related

- [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75130)
- [Prove the inequalities $1-\frac{x^2}{2}\le \cos(x)\le1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1513020)
- [Taylor expansion and trigonometric functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/818476)
- [Proving that $x - \frac{x^3}{3!} < \sin x < x$ for all $x>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/390899)

Comment: Gotcha, I figured Taylor's series had to be involved somehow, thank you very much!